# Does computing hashCode in HashMap and HashTable work differently?

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

I read couple of forums and I still fail to understand how is `hashCode()` computed and when?! I read in `HashMap` that `hashCode()` is called this way : `hash(key.hashCode());` and in `HashTable`, it is computed with both the key and pair : `h += e.key.hashCode() ^ e.value.hashCode();`. Are they computed differently in `HashMap` and `HashTable`?

When do `hashCode()` gets called? I assume it happens when you try do a `put(..)`, `get(..)` or `delete(..)`?

Comment: You could just look at the source-code...

Comment: The value can't be used to compute the hash, obviously. Otherwise, how could the get() method work to recompute the hash wihout any value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be confusing two completely different uses of `hashCode` here, both of which exist in both `HashMap` and `Hashtable`.

The first, inside methods like `put` and `get`, is to compute the hash of a key to find an entry in the table of entries. That is what `hash(key.hashCode())` is doing.

The second is inside the `hashCode` method *of the `HashMap` or `Hashtable` itself*, which is computing a single hash for the whole object. That uses the hashes of every key and value in the table - that's what `h += e.key.hashCode() ^ e.value.hashCode()` is doing.

Answer (score 2):

The `hashCode()` of the `key` gets called when you put an item into the map:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
...
int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
...
}
```

so that the new entry with the specified `key, value and hash code` can be added to the specified bucket.

It is also called when you are trying to retrieve a `value` from the `map` against the given `key` to find the bucket that has the required `Entry`. Again if you call `containsKey` to check whether a given key exists in the `map`, it uses `hashCode` to find the `bucket` that contains the `Entry`.